# How to get actual path from location in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the path which is matched with routes.
my routes are

```
<Route path="/admin/project/:id" element={<ProjectLayout />} title="ProjectLayout">
   <Route path="/admin/project/:id/dashboard" element={<ProjectDashboard />} title="ProjectDashboard" />
   <Route path="/admin/project/:id/tasks" element={<ProjectTasks />} title="ProjectTasks" />                            
</Route>
```

I am using useLocation() to get pathname.

It return "/admin/project/123/dashboard" but I am expecting "/admin/project/:id/dashboard"

Please help me.

Comment: You can write an utility function based on regex checking which accepts the actual location and returns what kind of path it is.

Comment: try replacing the uselocation output for ur need with :id such
var newString=location.pathname.replace( /\d+/g, ':id');

Comment: why not just pass the path as prop to the Component itself as a string ...  `element={<ProjectDashboard  pathUsed="/admin/project/:id/dashboard" />}` something as so  ?